# Alternative for Normalized Difference Built-up Index (NDBI) using satellite imagery with RGB & NIR bands

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

I am currently working with Planet SkySat multispectral imagery in Google Earth Engine ([dataset description](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/SKYSAT_GEN-A_PUBLIC_ORTHO_MULTISPECTRAL?hl=en)). It has only Red, Green, Blue and NIR bands. My objective is slum mapping and for this, NDBI (Normalized Difference Built-Up Index) is an important index.

Is there any alternative for NDBI (for building extraction) using the available four bands (as NDBI requires SWIR bands next to NIR)?